# if your rise is 7.25" and your tread is 11.5" but you also have a 3" nosing is this legal

Tags: stairs

[image: rise is 7.25", tread is 11.5", nosing is 3", legal???]
If the rise is 7.25" and the tread is 11.5" and the nosing is 3", is this legal

Comment: In which jurisdiction?

Comment: In my jurisdiction the handrail has to return to the wall.

Comment: I would say it is a trip hazard but since your stairs are on the wall i think you will have have other forces causing you to fall down.

Comment: Is your 11.5” measured from nosing to nosing? (You can’t count what is under the nosing.)

Comment: Code allows 8” maximum riser and 9” minimum tread. (ICC R311.)

Comment: Are yiu saying the nose is 3” thick or protrudes 3” from riser?

Answer (score 1):

Its going to matter where in the world you are as looking at your localbuilding code will tell you if it is legal, but from the common sense side, there is a reason why a nosing of ~1" give or take 1/2" is typical - becasue it is safer than 2" or 3" or 1'.......

I'm going to bet a 3" nosing is not allowed in your area (or any???) but again, check the code. It promotes a tripping hazard.

Comment: On the other hand I see steps with no verticals, 100% open.

Comment: agreed, but those steps have the 10" clear "facing" right? In that case no issue, in this case, if the open face is 7" due to 3" of overhang, its a tripping hazard (I beleive code suggests nosing <= 1.25" in most areas?)

Comment: @Harper Yes, the riser can be “open”, if you cannot Pass a 4” diameter ball through it, when the riser is 30” or more above the lower floor.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about legal or "to Code".

As long as the 3 inch nose never snaps off. It's all about safety and stability, and making sure no one will get hurt over time.